# How to pass a string to a django url path through a hyperlink?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a Django website that shows overwatch maps for strategic purposes. I have created a page that shows all the maps. Each map is wrapped in a hyperlink that is supposed to dynamically display information about that map.

```
<div id="item">
    <a href="{% url 'overwatch:maps/blizzard' %}">
        <img
            src="{% static 'pics/blizzard-world.jpg' %}"
                    alt="Blizzard World"
        />
    </a>
</div>
```

When you click on the map picture I want the url to send a string to the url path:

```
app_name = "overwatch"
path('maps/<str:mapName>', views.mapStrategies, name='maps/<str:mapName>'),
```

After that this view is supposed to be rendered.

```
def mapStrategies(request, mapName):
    return render(request, "overwatch/maps/mapStrategies.html", {
        "mapName": mapName
        })
```

The url pattern is not recognized when the map is clicked on. However I can type in the url and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify url params i.e. `<str:mapName>` in `name` of path, so it should be:

```py
path('maps/<str:mapName>/', views.mapStrategies, name='maps_strategies'),
```

Then in the html send any string for `mapName` param,  so:

```html
<div id="item">
    <a href="{% url 'overwatch:maps_strategies' 'some_map_name' %}">
        <img
            src="{% static 'pics/blizzard-world.jpg' %}"
                    alt="Blizzard World"
        />
    </a>
</div>
```

> **Note:** Always give `/` at the end of every route.